# Laravel error on save pivot table in transaction mode

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, transactions

I am trying to create a new record in during transaction by creating the model instance and then decorate all properties.

### Post model

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function authors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
       User::class, 'blog_post_authors', 'post_id', 'author_id'
    );
}
```

### Saving model

```
// start transaction mode
DB::beginTransaction();

$postModel = new Post(
    ['title' => 'Hello world!']
);

// relate authors
$postModel->authors()->attach(7);

\DB::commit();
```

However, its throwing an exception even before transaction being committed.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'post_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `blog_post_authors` (`author_id`, `post_id`) values (7, ?))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should save the Post Model , maybe you missed that:

```
DB::beginTransaction();

$postModel = new Post(
    ['title' => 'Hello world!']
);
$postModel->save();

// relate authors
$postModel->authors()->attach(7);

\DB::commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a `$postModel` in terms that it is created in php, but it is not saved to the database yet, and therefore does not yet have an `id` since the id it's probably an auto-incrementing value determined by the database.

So first save your postModel, than apply the author relation.

Either do:
`$postModel = Post::create([...]);`
or add: 
`$postModel->save();`

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be solved, but I encountered the same error and in my case the problem was the `$incrementing` property of the model, which in case of a model that extends Pivot class is set to `false`.
Setting it to `true` solved my issue.

For reference: [Laravel sync with database transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76042186/9338657)